# How to inject into an interceptor?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have configured a security-interceptor which should have the user-session object (which is a singleton) injected here is what I tried:

```
public DependencyInjection extends AbstractModule{
  //Class that has AccessLevel Annoation
  bind(InterfaceA.class).to(ImplA.class);
  bind(UserPersistor.class).to(UserPersistorImpl.class);
  //My session that I wish to inject
  bind(UserSession.class).to(UserSessionHandler.class);

  bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(AccessLevel.class),
                new SecurityInterceptor(getProvider(UserSession.class)));
}
```

Here my UserSessionHandler:

```
@Singleton
public class UserSessionHandler implements UserSession {

private UserLevel userLevel = UserLevel.DEFAULT;
private final UserPersistor userPersistor;

@Inject
public UserSessionHandler(UserPersistor userPersistor) {
    this.userPersistor = userPersistor;
}

@Override
public boolean loginUser(String userName, String password) {
    Benutzer user = userPersistor.getUserByName(userName);
    if (user == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (user.getKennwort().equals(password)) {
            userLevel = UserLevel.valueOf(user.getRolleId().getBezeichnung().toUpperCase());
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean logoutUser() {
    userLevel = UserLevel.DEFAULT;
    return true;
}

@Override
public UserLevel getUserLevel() {
    return userLevel;
}
```

}

Here how the SecurityInterceptor currently looks like:

```
@Singleton
public class SecurityInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    private final Provider<UserSession> session;
    @Inject
    public SecurityInterceptor(Provider<UserSession> session){
        this.session = session;
    }




    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        AccessLevel[] acessRoles = invocation.getMethod().getAnnotationsByType(AccessLevel.class);

        List<UserLevel> allowedRoles = new ArrayList<>();

        for(AccessLevel accessRole: acessRoles){
            allowedRoles.add(accessRole.value());
        }

        //Make sure that User has one of the allowed Access-Levels
        if (!allowedRoles.contains(session.get().getUserLevel())) {
            throw new InvalidAccessException("No Access allowed with userlevel" + session.get().getUserLevel());
        }
        return invocation.proceed();

    }

}
```

Now I managed to get it working in my Mockito-Test with a binding to an instance like this:

```
bind(MockInterface.class).to(MockClass.class);
bind(UserSession.class).toInstance(user);
bind(UserPersistor.class).toInstance(mockUserPersistor);

bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(AccessLevel.class),
                        new SecurityInterceptor(getProvider(UserSession.class)));
```

However I don't want to create an instance myself but want the once guice is creating. How can I do that, or what am I currently doing wrong?

EDIT: My main issue is that the usersession seems to be different to the one that is generated. Here a simple example:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new DependencyInjection());
UserSession session = injector.createInstance(UserSession.class);
InterfaceA methodCaller = injector.createInstance(InterfaceA.class);
if(session.loginUser("a","b")){
  System.out.println(session.getUserLevel().toString()); //Returns Admin
}
methodCaller.callMethodWithAnnotation();
```

Now when I check the session.getUserLevel in the interceptor I get "Default"

EDIT2: My endgoal is to have the same session instance in my interceptor and anywhere I used UserSession

Comment: It somehow works when I use a Provider<UserSession>  in the class that calls the login-function instead of just a DI UserSession. Can anybody explain to me what the difference is? In my eye's it shouldn't matter since its a singleton for guice anyway

Comment: Why SecurityInterceptor is @Singleton? I guess, when it's singleton, if you just @Inject UserSession, you will always get the same instance injected. When you use Provider, it injects different instances.

Comment: Justas But shouldn't the provider also respect @singleton? Currently I have a provider that has an @Inject UserSession and is used instead of the injection. Is that good or bad design?

Comment: Did you use any example to implement your code? It's quite difficult to understand your code.

Comment: I used the following example: @Justas http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.ch/2009/01/guice-tutorial-part-2-method.html
However he seems to have used an attribute injection, where I would prefer a constructor based (since all my others are also constructor based)